PayPal REST API /v2/scim/Users Endpoint Hangs Indefinitely
As the title states, the /v2/scim/Users endpoint hangs indefinitely when I try to make a request to it, so far both in Node JS code and from Postman. As far as I can tell, I'm implementing my HTTP request according to the documentation:
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/scim/Users/7XRNGHV24HABC', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/scim+json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <Access-Token>'
    }
});

What could be the issue here? Do I need a different type of access token than the others? For example, transactions listing is working fine with the same access token. I also find the scim+json content type questionable.
My ultimate goal is to get to the email for my customers, so I'd be interested if there is any easier way to do this.

Other than that API reference I can't find documentation on that SCIM PayPal API, but you mention that your goal is to get the email of your customers. Use Log in with PayPal for that purpose.
